# Searching a numeric value from a (n)varchar column

Tags: c#, sql-server, solr

Am implementing full-text search using solr and I would appreciate it if someone could offer me some help with some problem am facing.

My schema.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="products" version="1.2">
    <types>
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
            <fieldType name="concatenated" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
                <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    splitOnNumerics="1"
                            catenateWords="1"
                            catenateNumbers="1"
                            catenateAll="1"
                            preserveOriginal="1"
                    />
                </analyzer>
            </fieldType>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field name="keyid" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true"/>
        <field name="combined" type="concatenated" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>keyid</uniqueKey>
    <defaultSearchField>combined</defaultSearchField> 
    <copyField source="keyid" dest="keyid"/>  
    <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

And my data-config.xml file looks as follows:

```
<dataConfig>
    <document name="products">
        <entity name="product" query="SELECT ProductId AS keyid, CONVERT(VARCHAR(18), ProductId) + ' ' + ProductName AS combined FROM Products"
            <field column="keyid" name="keyid"/>
            <field column="combined" name="combined"/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And I have a record like follows in my Products table

**ProductId|ProductName**

**239289231|Windows 7**

Assuming a successful setup and indexing (using `localhost:8089/sorl/dataimport?command=full-import`), why would I not get results when I run this query:

**Scenario 1:**`localhost:8089/solr/select?q=combined:239289233`

Yet the queries below do give me results (one searching from the **keyid** field and another from the **combined** field):

**Scenario 2:**`localhost:8089/solr/select?q=combined:Windows`

**Scenario 3:**`localhost:8089/solr/select?q=keyid:239289233`

Is the problem the TokenizerFactory or FilterFactory that am using here? Shouldn't Solr treat `ProductId` as a string after its cast to `VARCHAR` and concatenated - hence make it possible to call it out the way am doing in `Scenario 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue here is the tokenizers. Your first tokenizer, the `LowerCaseTokenizerFactory` completely strips off the numbers, so that is why you cannot find search and find any values with your ProductId values. In your example case, it is only indexing the word Windows.

I am assuming you perhaps want to lowercase the value, so you would want to use the `StandardTokenizerFactory` as your tokenizer, and `LowerCaseFilterFactory` as a filter to lowercase the values. That will include the ProductId value as a token to be indexed and have NGrams built against the following tokens - `239289231`, `Windows` and `7`.

Here is a suggested modified fieldType

```
  <fieldType name="concatenated" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
     <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" 
            maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
             splitOnCaseChange="0"
             splitOnNumerics="1"
             catenateWords="1"
             catenateNumbers="1"
             catenateAll="1"
             preserveOriginal="1"
             />
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

Also, I would recommend reviewing the [Analyzers, Tokenizers and Token Filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) page on the Solr Wiki for examples of how the various ones work, if you have not already. In this case it was just a mix up between a tokenizer and a filter I believe.

Comment: Thanks. And I will work towards becoming more familiar with Analyzers, Tokenizers and Token Filters.